# Merging 3 Tables, Limiting 1 Table With Multiple Fields Needed

Tags: mysql

Been looking into this for awhile. Hoping someone might be able to provide some insight. I have 3 tables. All of which I'm grabbing multiple columns, but the 3rd I need to limit the output to just the most recent timestamp entry, BUT still display multiple columns.
If I have the following data [ Please see SQL Fiddle ]:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84b91/6

The fiddle is a list of (names) in Table1(users), (job_name,years) in Table2(job), and then (score, timestamp) in Table3(job_details). All linked together by the users id.

I am definitely not great at MYSQL. I know I'm missing something.. possibly a series of JOINs. I have been able to get Table 1, Table 2 and one column of Table 3 by doing this:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.job_name, b.years,
(select c.timestamp
 from job_details as c
 where c.user_id = a.id
 order by c.timestamp desc limit 1) score
from users a, job as b where a.id = b.user_id;
```

At this point, I can get multiple column data on the first two columns, limit the 3rd to one value and sort that value on the last timestamp...

My question is: How does one go about adding a second column to the limit? In the example in the fiddle, I'd like to add the score as well as the timestamp to the output.

I'd like the output to be:

NAME, JOB, YEARS, SCORE, TIMESTAMP. The last two columns would only be the last entry in job_details sorted by the most recent TIMESTAMP.

Please let me know if more information is required! Thank you for your time!
T

Comment: Post the desired result here.

Comment: Just edit your answer.

Comment: @tdotcspot, i see multiple time stamp for a user, in that case, any score is fine?

Comment: I've edited the link to the updated Fiddle. @radar, any score should be fine as long as its the most recent timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.job_name, b.years, c.timestamp, c.score
from users a 
INNER JOIN job as b ON a.id = b.user_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT  jd.user_id, jd.timestamp, jd.score
            FROM job_details as jd
            INNER JOIN (select user_id, MAX(timestamp) as tstamp
                   from job_details
                   GROUP BY user_id) as max_ts ON jd.user_id = max_ts.user_id
                                                AND jd.timestamp = max_ts.tstamp
            ) as c ON a.id = c.user_id
            ;
```

Comment: For those that might stumble upon this and want to see the output. Thank you for the help. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84b91/9